# Is there any way to soar on Latias or Latios without mega evolving them?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

When you use the Eon Flute to soar on Latias or Latios, you automatically mega evolve them. If you take away their mega stone, the game will transfer it to to them when you soar, even if you give it to a different pokemon to hold.

I don't like how their mega evolved forms look like and would like to soar on a regular Latios/Latias. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, because only MegaLatios and MegaLatias can let you soar in the Sky, it's a feature you can only exploit with their mega-evolution.

As [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Soaring_in_the_sky) says:

> Once the Eon Flute is used, Latias or Latios will come to the the Player's side and Mega Evolve. This is regardless to whether or not the Pokémon are present in the player's party, or even holding their respective Mega Stones.

They have to megaevolve if you want to soar the sky.

Comment: It's odd that it forces you to mega evolve them since you clearly flew on regular latios/latias to get to Southern Island the first time anyway. Oh well.